# Problems with HttpSessionState and HttpSessionStateBase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

We've been migrating a system from web forms to MVC 4 and now we are having problems with the sessions.

As you should know, the MVC controllers use HttpSessionStateBase and the WebForms (in this case, the classes) use HttpSessionState. The constructor of the classes take as parameter a HttpSessionState variable and the problem is when we are instantiating those classes from the controller.

I already read about using the HttpSessionStateWrapper to wrap the the HttpSessionState in the classes to avoid that problem, but I can't find anything about how to use it, usually I only find examples like: `HttpSessionStateWrapper Wrap = new HttpSessionStateWrapper("Parameter");`
But I don't get if I need another library or something, since I'm only importing System.Web.SessionState and I can't use that class, even in the Microsoft page I only find that this is supposed to be in System.Web.HttpSessionStateWrapper, but I can't find anything like that.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is other way around: you should not use `HttpSessionState` in MVC project, so you have to rewrite your "classes" using `HttpSessionStateBase`.

Comment: But as far as I know the classes can't use HttpSessionStateBase, only the MVC controllers. I think the way to go is using the HttpSessionStateWrapper to convert the HttpSessionState to HttpSessionStateBase, but I can only use it in the controller and a already have the HttpSessionStateBase there.
Thanks for taking your time to answer my question.

Comment: There's no limitation that some class in project can not use `HttpSessionStateBase`. So just go ahead and rewrite your code.

Comment: It's not like I'm being lazy and I don't want to change the code, if I could do that I would only need to change 2 constructor parameters. The problem is that I really can't use that in a class, if I'm writing in a controller I can use the three, HttpSessionStateBase, HttpSessionState and HttpSessionStateWrapper, but in a class I can only use HttpSessionState.

Comment: Ok, it looks like I only needed to use the `resolve` tool to be able to use the HttpSessionStateBase in a class, now I feel pretty dumb for that. 
Again, thank you so much for your help.